# Express.js do not open index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, npm

Issue came up, when I tried to run axpress.js solution, but it opens index.jade file from views folder and in browser I see result: "Welcome to Express" , but I would like to open my index.html file which is located in client directory -> index.html , when I run npm I am accessing to this location: http://localhost:3000/client/index.html , but this path my solution do not find.

In app.js file I set and define routes:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

routes folder: index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Where I have to setup my routing, because now I am getting 404 .

Comment: express.static is serving a directory called 'public', you'd have to put `index.html` in there

Comment: @tladuke it doesn't work.

Comment: In the second line of your current code, you have set the view engine to Jade. Express is currently only looking for `.jade` extension files to render.

Comment: @JorgeValle , yes but I want to run 'index.html' and it doesn't support html engine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name from index.html to index.jade.

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Create a new directory called views and move this html file to it and change the .html to .jade because you are using jade as your template engine.

Comment: it doesn't work